# Is there MDT UML2 Toold for Eclipse Indigo (3.7)?

Tags: eclipse, uml, mdtool, eclipse-mdt

Is there MDT UML2 Toold for Eclipse Indigo (3.7)? I'm a little confused, on this page [Model Development Tools (MDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=modeling.mdt) it says that the release should be on June 22 (2010??), however there is no release listed later on that page.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the sub-projects. Most MDT stuff is released with the standard release train. There is a release for Indigo and there will be one for Juno.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Papurus or Topcased for Eclipse Indigo as an UML Modeler. The other Ecipse Modeling tool has been discontinued.

Comment: There are many other commercial tools based on MDT, of course.